# Open Konsole terminal always in split view

Tags: kubuntu, konsole

I am using [`Konsole`](https://konsole.kde.org/) (the default terminal) in Kubuntu.
I am aware that I can split Konsole using <kbd>SHIFT + CTRL + 0</kbd>.

I would like Konsole to automatically split by default every time I launch it.

I have been unable to locate the settings for enabling this feature.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work.

Create a `json` file (filename `layout.json` or any filename you want) with this content:

```
{
  "Orientation": "Vertical",
  "Widgets": [
    {
      "SessionRestoreId": 0
    },
    {
      "SessionRestoreId": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

And to open a new Konsole using that layout you should run it with:

```bash
konsole --layout ./layout.json
```

---

Btw, you can save/load Tab Layouts by using directly the Konsole application, so if you want to save the current state of a Konsole Tab you should go to:

**View** -> **Save Tab Layout**

or
**View** -> **Load Tab Layout**

Nonetheless, in my case the Konsole application has the buttons differently, I have to go to:
 **More** -> **View** -> **Save Tab Layout**

---

And finally if you want the Konsole to open always with the custom layout (without using a command directly from terminal) you should edit the desktop file for Konsole, in my case: `org.kde.konsole.desktop` and this is located in: `/usr/share/applications` but maybe you have the file in: `/home/youruser/.local/share/applications`. So in order to run the Konsole app with a custom layout change the following directive:

```ini
Exec=konsole
```

to

```ini
Exec=konsole --layout /path/to/layout.json
```